# How to make a create form with select option in ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make a create form of nested attributes `todo` with select option on `project` and it must be in  `/projects/index.html.erb`
Here is *projects_controller.rb*

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all
  @todo = Todo.new
end
```

Models *project.rb* and *todo.rb*

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos, inverse_of: :project

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
  attributes[:title].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :todos
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
root 'projects#index'
    resources :projects do
        resources :todos
    end
```

And `/projects/index.html.erb`

```
<h1>Tasks</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>   
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% for project in @projects %>
  <tr><strong><%= project.title %></strong></tr>
  <% for todo in project.todos %>
    <ul>
    <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i create `todo.text` in certain `project.title` with select option in `/project/index.html.erb` . It should also look like [link](http://i.prntscr.com/3utLJmfHTt633iqzwSaG9g.png)

Comment: You want to create a todo, for which you want to select a project from the dropdown? In this case, you don't need the nested attributes. Just a select tag form helper, `f.select :project_id`. You can look up usage examples in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested form fields to work with the has_many association. Rails provides a [`fields_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) helper to do this for you.

I've adapted their documentation to your use case:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= form_for project do |project_form| %>
      ...
      <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
        <%= project_form.fields_for :todos, todo do |todo_fields| %>
            Text: <%= todo_fields.text_field :text %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also use a gem such as [`nested_form`](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) which will allow you to add and remove todos dynamically.

Comment: _Actually_, it appears that this mention of nested attributes was a misdirection. He can simply post a todo form with project_id field.